# Variable outside the loop marked as 'DU'-anomaly in PMD

Tags: java, pmd

I get a lot of this anomaly. Here BufferedData ist marked as DU' anomaly by PMD. What is wrong with this approach?

```
    private static void summUpBuffer(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
        List<String> bufferedData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
            bufferedData.add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't use `bufferedData` content.  Since that is a local variable, this code doesn't make sense. Please post the whole code.

Comment: You are adding elements to `bufferedData` but for what purpose? You are not accessing it or returning it.

Comment: Actually DU anomaly appeared in similar situation like this in other parts which were complex to post here. I used this code snippet just for demo, though not an accurate one. If I return bufferedDate then it is fine and it won't be marked an DU anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

'DU Anomaly' means the code might not do what you intended. Since you never use the variable `bufferedData`, it is flagged up due to being a pointless assignment.

In essense your method doesn't do anything. All its side effects are local and will be forgotten as soon as the method returns.
Complete the method and the warning will most likely go away.

---

Edit: Actually there is one side-effect, namely the reading of the `BufferedReader`. That's probably why `bufferedData` is the only thing flagged in this way.